# How to compile Jython program so as to generate .class files?

Tags: .class-file, jython-2.5

I know that Jython before version 2.5 can achieve this by using the command "jythonc". But I am using Jython 2.5.3 now.

What I need is very simple: I want the Jython to compile my Python code and generate the .class files (or Java bytecode) for me, as I would need these .class files to do some analysis works. But unfortunately, the interpreter just directly runs the program without leaving any intermediate representations behind.

P.S.: I'm using a Mac

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need class files?

Comment: @Antimony Yes, as I'm doing analysis on the .class files generated from different languages.

Comment: Well it sounds like Jython doesn't generate classfiles anymore. You might as well ask how to generate a classfile with Clang.